# How can I magnify a Javascript array by a given scale factor?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a Javascript function that magnifies a 2D Javascript array by a given integer scale factor. The width and height of the "magnified" array should be twice the width and height of the original array, as shown in the example below.

```
function magnifyArray(arr, scaleFactor){
    // magnify arr by the given scale factor
}

var arr1 = [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 0]
]

var arr2 = magnifyArray(arr1, 2);
console.log(arr2);
//arr2 should now be:
//[[0, 0, 1, 1],
//[0, 0, 1, 1],
///[1, 1, 0, 0],
//[1, 1, 0, 0]
//]
```

Comment: What's exactly the problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by magnify?

Comment: Specifically, I want to do this because I'm creating a Javascript fractal generator, but that's probably not the only use case of this algorithm.

Comment: @David See the example - I thought it was clear from the example I gave.

Comment: @Anderson: Does it have to handle other factors than positive integers?

Comment: You want each value to be repeated according to the 'scale factor'?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen No, it doesn't need to do that - that would be impossible.

Comment: @DavidThomas yes - see the example in the original post.

Comment: @Anderson: It's not impossible. Anything that scales images does it all the time - it tends to involve some form of interpolation.

Comment: This should work only for 2-dimensional arrays?

Comment: @SergeyS It should work for 2-dimensional arrays, but it would be possible to generalize it to arrays of any dimension.

Comment: See my answer for any-dimension arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This recursive approach will work for arrays with any number of dimensions:

```
function mag(arr, scale) {
    var res = [];
    if(!arr.length)
        return arr;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var temp = mag(arr[i], scale);
        for (var k = 0; k < scale; k++) {
            res.push(temp.slice ? temp.slice(0) : temp);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

For not-arrays it will return the object itself.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2T4J/4/

**[EDIT]**: added .slice(0) to copy array elements to new array object (this maybe is not necessary for your scenario)

Comment: It would be useful to post this on jsfiddle (for testing and debugging purposes). I can't wait to try it out. :)

Answer (score 4):

oh, the ugly

```
function mag(matrix, scale) {
    var rows = matrix.length, cols = matrix[0].length;
    var mat = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var row = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < scale; k++) {
                row.push(matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < scale; k++) {
            mat.push(row);
            // or use mat.push(row.slice(0)); to clone duplicate rows
        }
    }
    return mat;
}
```

note that i don't clone the array objects when i duplicate the rows. this could lead to unexpected results if you modify a row later, but its an efficiency gain otherwise.

Comment: Will this only work for 2-dimensional arrays, or will it work for arrays of any dimension?

Comment: @AndersonGreen 2d array only.

Comment: See my answer for any-dimension arrays.

Answer (score 1):

For an array of arrays of simple values, magnifyArray will produce your example result.

```
function replicateEntries( a , x ) {
    var i, j, result = new Array();
    for ( i = 0 ; i < a.length ; ++i ) {
        for ( j = 0 ; j < x ; ++j ) result.push( a[i] );
    }
    return result;
}

function magnifyArray( a , x ) {
    var i, rows = new Array();
    for ( i = 0 ; i < a.length ; ++i ) {
        rows.push( replicateEntries( a[i] , x ) );
    }
    return replicateEntries( rows , x );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it the hard and boring way as there is nothing included.

For example :

```
var a =
[
[0, 1],
[1, 0]
];
var scale = 2;
​var b =​ [];
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    var bi = [];
    var ai = a[i];
    for (var j=0; j<ai.length; j++) {
        for (var k=0; k<scale; k++)  bi.push(ai[j]);
    }
    for (var k=0; k<scale; k++)b.push(bi);
}​
```

Comment: Do we really have to write everything ? I edited to adapt it to any scale... But I'd really like to know why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: Be aware that by pushing the same array multiple times they will be the same array instance, and changing the value in one cell in your matrix will change values in other cells as well.

Comment: @dystroy The solution is much more comprehensive than it was before - hopefully all the downvotes will be removed eventually.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yes. This could be changed but I see it as an optimization (now that you pointed it, as I didn't think about it before).